# jcomboBox with two columns in the drop down let but only one selected value

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

```
class ComboItem {
int id;
String name;

ComboItem(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(this.id) + "-" + this.name;
}

public int getItem() {
    return this.id;
}
}
```

I created a JComboBox that I filled with items that have two variables: an id and a name (code shown above). I overrided the toString function so that the combo box displays both fields with a - between them. What I want to do is to show only id when a user selects something from the drop down list. I want the user to be able to see both the id and the name when he clicks on the arrow, but I want the combo box to display just the id once the user has made his selection. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: A the ListCellRenderer interface method, `getListCellRendererComponent(...)` has a boolean *selected* parameter that you could use perhaps to decide whether or not to show just the id or to show more information. Consider playing with this.

Comment: **don't** override the toString .. the visual reprresentation is the exclusive task of the cellRenderer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a custom renderer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

Comment: When using a custom renderer you should also implement a `KeySelectionManager` otherwise you will break the default functionality of the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own ListCellRenderer.
See JComboBox#setRenderer method.

For example:

```
JComboBox<ComboItem> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new ComboItem[]{new ComboItem(1, "test")});
    comboBox.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<ComboItem>() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends ComboItem> list, ComboItem value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            return new Label(Integer.toString(value.getItem()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: -1 You should not be creating a new JLabel. The idea of a renderer is to use a single component for all rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Create a custom renderer
2. Implement a `KeySelectionManager` (because the custom renderer will break the default functionality of a combo box.

See [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and a solution which does both of the above for you.

You will need to customize the renderer implementation (inaddition to the suggestion given in the above link). The index for the selected value will be -1. So you will need code in your renderer to display the selected value versus the values in the drop down list. Something like:

```
if (index == -1)
    //  display the id
else
    //  display the id and name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments made by the various users I was able to come up with a solution that worked for me. i will post it here in case someone might benefit from it.
I re-wrote the toString() function in the class to display just the id of the item. Apparently JComboBox displays the selected item by calling the toString() function. I then wrote another function called full() that displays the id and the name together. Finally, I implemented a ListCellRenderer that called toString() if the item was selected (index == -1) and called full() if the item was not selected.

```
class ComboItem {
int id;
String name;

ComboItem(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(this.id);
}

public String full() {
    return Integer.toString(this.id) + "-" + this.name;
}
}

class MyComboRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
public MyComboRenderer () {
    setOpaque(true);
    setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    } else {
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }
    ComboItem c = (ComboItem) value;
    if (index == -1)
        setText(c.toString());
    else
        setText(c.full());
    return this;
}
}
```

Comment: -1 **don't** mis-use toString, +1 for the custom renderer, zeroes out :-) Repeating: the visual representation of some object is the exclusive task of the renderer, the data has nothing to do with it.